# Inherit/subclass from `tuple` with correct indexing and slicing

Tags: python, python-3.x, mypy

i am trying to sublass `tuple` and make `mypy` happy in the process. i would like to make slicing and indexing work.

here is what i have tried:

```
from functools import singledispatchmethod
from typing import Iterable


class MyIntTuple(tuple[int, ...]):
    def __new__(cls, iterable: Iterable[int]) -> "MyIntTuple":
        return super().__new__(cls, iterable)  # type: ignore

    @singledispatchmethod
    def __getitem__(self, value: slice, /) -> "MyIntTuple":
        return MyIntTuple(super().__getitem__(value))

    @__getitem__.register
    def __getitem__(self, value: int, /) -> int:
        return super().__getitem__(value)
```

this almost works except for slicing:

```
a = MyIntTuple(range(12))
print(a)        # (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
print(a[3])     # 3 
print(a[3:6])   # (3, 4, 5)
b = a[5:8]
print(type(a))  # <class '__main__.MyIntTuple'>
print(type(b))  # <class 'tuple'>
```

the problem here is that slicing should return an instance of `MyIntTuple`. i seem to have gotten that wrong.

also `mypy` is not happy about this:

```
error: Name "__getitem__" already defined on line 488  [no-redef]
```

the subs in `tuple` are

```
Superclass:
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, SupportsIndex, /) -> int
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, slice, /) -> Tuple[int, ...]
```

how do i correctly overload those? is `functools.singledispatchmethod` the wrong way to go? or am i using it incorrectly?

Comment: Do you actually need the subclass? `MyIntTuple = NewType('MyIntTuple', tuple[int, ...])`, with `a = MyIntTuple(tuple(range(12))`, may be sufficient.

Comment: @chepner oh. had not thought of that. will try. could i still add methods (in the real example there are additional methods in this class)? or would i have to monkey-patch those?

Comment: No, if you need additional methods, you'll need a subclass. Just wanted to make sure that you weren't using a subclass *just* to specialize the type from `tuple` to `tuple[int, ...]`.

Comment: Just to make sure: do you really need `singledispatchmethod`? Since only two options are considered, I'd probably go with `isinstance` branches in a single method body. Then you can use `typing.overload` decorator to replicate superclass typing from typeshed (that one shown under "Superclass:" in `mypy` output).

Comment: @SUTerliakov i have no idea if `singledispatchmethod` is needed... this was my first shot at solving this. i saw no other way to make mypy happy. i'd be interested to see a different solution!

Comment: Here you are: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=11493b635ff1c147a72426402cf8581d (I'll prepare a more detailed answer in a while, just code for now, and [`overload` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload))

Comment: @SUTerliakov that does look nice! will mypy not get confused when i use indexing or slicing? will it know that `my_int_tuple[3]` returns an `int` and `my_int_tuple[3:7]` a `MyIntTuple` only (as opposed to `MyIntTuple`)?

Comment: Oh, thanks for reminder, preparing an answer. `reveal_type` in the bottom shows the `mypy` type (type that `mypy` assigns to expression in parentheses), so no confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the individual implementations a different name from the "main" function:

```
@__getitem__.register
def _(self, value: int, /) -> int:
    return super().__getitem__(value)
```

Also, the implementation for slices should be separate from the "main" function (which is used as the fallback for unrecognized argument types), and the int implementation should really take anything that supports `__index__`.

Since `MyIntTuple` isn't defined yet, you'll have to pass a type to `register` explicitly for the slice implementation, so it doesn't have to look at the annotations. Also, you can remove your `__new__` implementation - the inherited implementation will work fine:

```
from functools import singledispatchmethod
from typing import SupportsIndex

class MyIntTuple(tuple[int, ...]):
    @singledispatchmethod
    def __getitem__(self, arg, /):
        raise TypeError("Can't index MyIntTuple with argument of type {!r}".format(type(arg)))

    @__getitem__.register(slice)
    def _(self, value: slice, /) -> "MyIntTuple":
        return MyIntTuple(super().__getitem__(value))

    @__getitem__.register
    def _(self, value: SupportsIndex, /) -> int:
        return super().__getitem__(value)
```

Comment: that is indeed a mistake i made! thanks! but mypy still complains: `error: Signature of "__getitem__" incompatible with supertype "tuple"  [override]` and more...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: You still need to fix your signature too. Answer expanded.

Comment: while this looks pretty good it does not run (on python 3.11): `NameError: name 'MyIntTuple' is not defined` (in the line with `def _(self, value: slice, /) -> "MyIntTuple":`).  and `mypy` emits 4 errors.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: ...right, `functools.singledispatchmethod` is going to try to call `get_type_hints`, which will try to evaluate the forward reference. Fixed.

Comment: I'm not seeing those mypy errors, though.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: maybe ```from __future__ import annotations``` can solve the ```NameError``` problem.

Comment: yup. mypy errors are gone & everything works! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

`overload` in the signature `mypy` presents to you as expected is not some abstract thing, but a reference to [decorator from `typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.overload).

Here's what you can do to match supertype definition:

```py
from typing import Iterable, SupportsIndex, overload
from typing_extensions import reveal_type

class MyIntTuple(tuple[int, ...]):
    # Your main problem was here: `int` is much stricter than `SupportsIndex`
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, value: SupportsIndex, /) -> int: ...
    @overload
    def __getitem__(self, value: slice, /) -> "MyIntTuple": ...
    
    def __getitem__(self, value: SupportsIndex | slice, /) -> "MyIntTuple | int":
        if isinstance(value, slice):
            return MyIntTuple(super().__getitem__(value))

        return super().__getitem__(value)


t = MyIntTuple((1,2,3))
reveal_type(t)  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.MyIntTuple"
reveal_type(t[0])  # N: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
reveal_type(t[1:])  # N: Revealed type is "__main__.MyIntTuple"

# And here's why "SupportsIndex"
class MySomething:
    def __index__(self) -> int:
        return 1

reveal_type(t[MySomething()])  # N: Revealed type is "builtins.int"
```

The snippet above shows a problem with using `int`: this restriction should be weakened, because narrower argument types are violating LSP. Actual `tuple` can use a `slice` or anything with `__index__` dunder method defined, not just `int` in  `__getitem__`.

With `overload` and `SupportsIndex` in place, you are almost ready. The only change you need is to swap overloads order: same overloads order is enforced by `mypy`, and `Sequence` puts `SupportsIndex` signature first (try to swap them back and watch the error). In this case it is not critical, but in general different overloads order may change the type resolution. Overloads are tried in the definition order, the topmost wins. If signatures overlap, usually you'll see an extra `mypy` error - but better keep overloads in order anyway. Here's what inverse order would generate:

```
main.py:6: error: Signature of "__getitem__" incompatible with supertype "tuple"  [override]
main.py:6: note: Overload variants must be defined in the same order as they are in "tuple"
```

The code above [typechecks](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.10&flags=strict&gist=11493b635ff1c147a72426402cf8581d) with `--strict`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with `singledispatchmethod`.

```
from __future__ import annotations
from functools import singledispatchmethod
from typing import Iterable, Sequence

class MyIntTuple(tuple[int, ...]):
    def __new__(cls, iterable: Iterable[int]) -> MyIntTuple:
        return super().__new__(cls, iterable)  # type: ignore

    @singledispatchmethod
    def __getitem__(self) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError

    @__getitem__.register
    def _(self, value: slice, /) -> MyIntTuple:
        return MyIntTuple(super().__getitem__(value))

    @__getitem__.register
    def _(self, value: int, /) -> int:
        return super().__getitem__(value)
```

```
a = MyIntTuple(range(12))
print(a)        # (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
print(a[3])     # 3 
print(a[3:6])   # (3, 4, 5)
b = a[5:8]
print(type(a))  # <class '__main__.MyIntTuple'>
print(type(b))  # <class '__main__.MyIntTuple'>
```